# some register.inclusion_tag error in my code using django

Tags: python, django

my helloworld_tags:

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

def show_profile():
    return {"eee": '333'}
register.inclusion_tag("b.html")(show_profile)
```

my view:

```
def b(request):
    return render_to_response('b.html')
```

my html:

```
{% load helloworld_tags%} 
 dsad {{ eee }}
```

but only show 'dsad' ,not show 'dsad333'

why??

thanks

**updated**

but when i set this in c.html:

```
{% load helloworld_tags%}
```

and change the view:

```
def b(request):
    return render_to_response('c.html')
```

and the b.html is:

```
 dsad {{ eee }}
```

it is show nothing now ,

why ?

thanks

**updated2**

it is ok now ,when i add this to c.html:

```
{% load helloworld_tags%} 
{% show_profile %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can't possibly work. You need one template for the view to render, and **another different** template for the inclusion template. You can't use the same template for both uses, it simply doesn't make any sense.